# Error uploading an image in symfony 3.4

Tags: image, symfony, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image in symfony 3, but when i execute my controller display me this error message  "Call to a member function guessExtension() on string ".  Before the image was stored in my directory web/uploads/images only and not in my database. And when i try to fix this problem, i have this error.

This is my entity:

```
namespace Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

 /**
 * Media
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="media")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Repository\MediaRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */ 

 class Media 
 {
 /**
  * @var int
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
  private $id;

  /**
  * @var string
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
  */
  private $url;

  /**
  * @var string
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
  */
  private $alt;


  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string")
  *
  * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Ajouter une image valide")
  * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif" })
  */
  private $image;

 // On ajoute cet attribut pour y stocker le nom du fichier temporairement
 private $tempFilename;

  // On modifie le setter de File, pour prendre en compte l'upload d'un 
  fichier 
  lorsqu'il en existe déjà un autre

  public function getImage()
  {
    return $this->image;
  }
   public function setImage($image)
  {
  $this->image = $image;
  return $this;

  // On vérifie si on avait déjà un fichier pour cette entité
  if (null !== $this->url) {
   // On sauvegarde l'extension du fichier pour le supprimer plus tard
   $this->tempFilename = $this->url;

   // On réinitialise les valeurs des attributs url et alt
   $this->url = null;
   $this->alt = null;
   } 
 }

  /**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
  public function preUpload()
 {
  // Si jamais il n'y a pas de fichier (champ facultatif)
  if (null === $this->image) {
   return;
  }

  // Le nom du fichier est son id, on doit juste stocker également son 
  extension
 // Pour faire propre, on devrait renommer cet attribut en « extension », 
  plutôt que « url »
  $this->url = $this->image->guessExtension();  **Error location**

  // Et on génère l'attribut alt de la balise <img>, à la valeur du nom du 
  fichier sur le PC de l'internaute
  $this->alt = $this->image->getClientOriginalName();
  } 

  /**
  * @ORM\PostPersist()
  * @ORM\PostUpdate()
  */
   public function upload()
  {
  // Si jamais il n'y a pas de fichier (champ facultatif)
  if (null === $this->image) {
  return;
  }

 // Si on avait un ancien fichier, on le supprime
 if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
   $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this- 
   >tempFilename;
  if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
    unlink($oldFile);
    }
   }

 // On déplace le fichier envoyé dans le répertoire de notre choix
  $this->image->move(
  $this->getUploadRootDir(), // Le répertoire de destination
  $this->id.'.'.$this->url   // Le nom du fichier à créer, ici « id.extension 
  »
   );
  } 

 /**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function preRemoveUpload(){
 // On sauvegarde temporairement le nom du fichier, car il dépend de l'id
$this->tempFilename = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->url;
  } 

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
*/
 public function removeUpload(){
 // En PostRemove, on n'a pas accès à l'id, on utilise notre nom sauvegardé
 if (file_exists($this->tempFilename)) {
   // On supprime le fichier
   unlink($this->tempFilename);
 }
  } 

public function getUploadDir(){
// On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour un navigateur
return 'uploads/images';
 } 

protected function getUploadRootDir(){
 // On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour notre code PHP
 return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
  } 

public function getWebPath(){
return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getId().'.'.$this->getUrl();
 } 


 /**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set url
 *
 * @param string $url
 *
 * @return Media
 */
public function setUrl($url)
{
    $this->url = $url;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUrl()
{
    return $this->url;
}

/**
 * Set alt
 *
 * @param string $alt
 *
 * @return Media
 */
public function setAlt($alt)
{
    $this->alt = $alt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get alt
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAlt()
{
    return $this->alt;
}  

}
```

Then my controller:

```
  public function mediaEditAction(Request $request){



        $media = new Media();
        $form = $this->createForm(MediaType::class, $media);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $file = $media->getImage();
    $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
    $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('images_directory'),
            $fileName
        );
     $media->setImage($fileName);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($media);
        $em->flush();

      $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('Notice', 'Photo ajoutée 
  avec succès');
            // redirection
            $url = $this->generateUrl('medecin_parametre');
            // redirection permanente avec le status http 301 ::)))))
            return $this->redirect($url,301);

        }else{
            return $this- 
   >render('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin:mediaedit.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
        }

     }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try to get your file like this : `$file = $form->get('image')->getData();`

Comment: I've already do that but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тhe `image` property of your entity is a string, so it is normal to get the error.
If you want to use guess extension you can use like following:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

$file = new File($this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->image);

$this->url = $file->guessExtension();
```

Comment: I've trying that ant the error disappear. But a new error appear indicating "the file 211bcd455.jpeg" does not exist.

Comment: You must must provide the full path to the image '{absoluteImageDirectoryPath}/211bcd455.jpeg'. E.g '/var/www/yoursite.local/public/uploads/211bcd455.jpeg'

Comment: From what I see in the code you have getUploadRootDir method which can be used. I updated the answer.

Comment: ok It's done and this error was disappear.The next error display me that "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getClientOriginalName" of class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File".
It concern this code : $this->alt = $file->getClientOriginalName();